# Guy gets mugged, then his corporation sponsors the gang?

Tags: story-identification, books, dystopia

A novel series from the 90s or possibly late 80s. Thought the title was something like *Boedekker's Demons*, but I think I got the name mangled.

Corporate dystopia where a guy gets mugged but then turns the gang into a media sensation. At first everyone's profiting but then there's a falling out and things get dark. I think he gets the gang killed off.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Presumably this is [Boddekker's Demons](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/1081745.Boddekker_s_Demons) by Joe Clifford Faust. The publication details are [on the Internet Speculative Fiction Database here](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?9910).

[image: Boddekker's Demons]

> Boddekker's not just a faceless copywriter anymore, grinding out ads for VR simulators and mood/attitude orienters.  Now he's the "five-hundred-pound gorilla" of the Pembroke Hall agency, lumbering toward fame, fortune, and a fabled house in Princeton with shapely Honniker In Accounting.  All thanks to Ferman's Devils, the four New York City street thugs whose record-breaking (and bone-breaking) commercial has won them billions of fans and made gangster chic the latest rage.
>
> Yet Boddekker's new proteges are on the fast track to hell.  First they assault a famous talk show host.  Then they murder a former child celebrity in cold blood.  And the more outrageous their actions, the more popular they become.  So when another murder occurs, this time just too close to home, Boddekker knows he must find a way to take the Devils down.  He made them and he can break them...if they don't break him first.

The ISFDB is an immensely valuable resource for finding books when you half remember the title. I did [this advanced search](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/adv_search_results.cgi?USE_1=title_title&O_1=contains&TERM_1=demons&C=AND&USE_2=title_ttype&O_2=exact&TERM_2=NOVEL&USE_3=title_title&O_3=exact&TERM_3=&USE_4=title_title&O_4=exact&TERM_4=&USE_5=title_title&O_5=exact&TERM_5=&USE_6=title_title&O_6=exact&TERM_6=&ORDERBY=title_title&ACTION=query&START=0&TYPE=Title) for all novels with "demon" in the title and this book leaped out at me.

Comment: Yes, this is it! I can't believe I was just off by an extra d and k. I would have thought Google would still have gotten close.  I thought I was losing my memory. Thanks.

Comment: "The ISFDB is an immensely valuable resource for finding books when you half remember the title." - okay, I have to ask. I keep seeing people give ISFDB links as if they're actually useful, and now you're explicitly calling it an "immensely valuable resource", but whenever I visit such a link, there's almost nothing there. No summary, no topic, no character names, no themes, no hint whatsoever regarding what the work is about. Am I missing something? Do logged-in users see more information?

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica the ISFDB does allow entries to have summaries, but almost no-one ever types them in. So as you say it is pretty useless for searching the content of books. But it is without peer when it comes to searching for titles and authors, as in this case. For searching content I use Goodreads.